# Python Closure Program

Tags: python, function, closures

```
def maker(n):
    def action(x):
        return x ** n
    return action

f = maker(2)
f(2)
```

Resulting in: `4`

Can someone please elaborate, how `x` got his value when we are only defining(providing) value to `n`.

Comment: `maker(2)` is providing `n`, while `f(2)` is providing `x`. Your `maker` method returns the `action` method.

Answer (score 0):

When `maker(n)` is called it accepts a parameter `n` and a "hidden" method `action(x)` is declared. Note though that in the definition of `action(x)` we make use of the `n` variable.

So given:

```
def maker(n):

    ## ----------------
    ## define a new method that accepts a single parameter "x"
    ## but also uses "n" from the original call to maker()
    ## ----------------
    def action(x):
        return x ** n
    ## ----------------

    ## ----------------
    ## return our new function above
    ## ----------------
    return action
    ## ----------------
```

So when we do:

```
new_maker_based_method = maker(2)
```

What we have done is create a new method/function by getting it from `maker()` but not just any function, one where our parameter to `maker(2)` is significant.

Now we can all our new method:

```
print(new_maker_based_method(10))
```

and get a result of `100`

Let's see it in more detail in a little loop:

```
print("Powers of Two:")
for i in range(11):
    fn = maker(i)
    print(fn(2))

    ## or you can also just do
    ## print(maker(i)(2))
```

This will use `maker()` to create a new function every loop that we immediately call with a parameter of 2 giving us:

```
Powers of Two:
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
```